# A TV-series about a Space-Opera and a Captain floating in space

Tags: story-identification, tv

I saw a few episodes of a space-opera science fiction TV series a few years ago, but there are really only two parts I remember well.

One is a flashback where the captain is floating in space for some reason (doing repairs?) when space aliens warp in and blow up the fleet he is part of, leaving him breathing the last of the air in his space suit. Another main character, who I'll call the "wizard", shows up in his sleek black ship and rescues him.

The other plotline is when the "wizard" wants to visit the grave of his wife on some secret "wizard" asteroid in hyperspace. His ship can't travel there on its own, so he convinces the captain to rig his ship to his own, and they travel to the asteroid floating in a nebula lost in the hyperspace.

If anyone could tell me which series this is that would be wonderful; I've been trying to hunt it down.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This sounds like Babylon 5:Crusade.  A spinoff of the Babylon 5 tv series, it was one of my favorite series, though it didn't even last the entire first season before being cancelled.  In the flashback to a previous time, Captain Gideon's ship (he was a lieutenant at the time I believe) was destroyed by a Shadow vessel while he was outside in a spacesuit.  He was rescued near the end of his rope by a techno-mage named Galen.

In "current time", Galen joins up with the crew of the Excalibur, captained by the now Captain Gideon, to try and find a cure for a plague unleashed upon the Earth by a hostile alien race.