TV show where a spaceship's weapons were activated by the operator punching and kicking
I barely remember seeing what I think was a TV show, probably from the late 90's. It was about the adventures of a spaceship and crew. I remember it being absolutely atrocious.
The one thing I can picture is that, whenever there was going to be a battle, the weapon operator would slide down this little laundry chute into a chamber where she would have a full view of the ship's surroundings. She would then operate the ship's weapons by doing martial arts, punching and kicking to fire the ship's various weapons. It may have been the most cringey thing I've ever seen.
One specific scene I remember is the ship threading some very narrow passageway and she had to limbo under the projection as if her body was the ship.
Was this some kind of fever dream or was this actually a TV show? I can't find anything on Google with the combination of spaceship and punching/kicking.

Babylon 5: The Legend of the Rangers, as seen about 23 seconds into the intro.




Kyle Strand has indicated that there's more footage of the actual punching and kicking about 2:40 into this clip:




I'm looking for a reference image, but that's exactly how they did battles. Mentioned at https://www.reddit.com/r/babylon5/comments/px8pyl/the_karate_ship_weapon_system_thing_in/

Possible links https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12034/a-tv-series-about-a-space-opera-and-a-captain-floating-in-space/12037#12037 https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28916/sf-tv-series-where-fighter-pilots-lay-prone-to-fly-their-ships/28981#28981 or https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/287930/old-sci-fi-space-movie-with-humans-and-aliens-working-together-in-same-ship/287934#287934

Was it actually in Crusade? I only remember it in Rangers

What Radhil said.

@Radhil: I remember seeing it in Crusade, but it has, admittedly, been over a decade... and boy have those computer graphics not aged well.

Definitely not in Crusade, but would upvote the identification of The Legend of the Rangers.  (TLotR itself was the worst B5 production I can think of and deserves no positive votes for anything.)

:) Fixed until I find any indication it did show up in Crusade.

Starting at 2:40 here, there's a longer sequence of clips showing these battles: https://youtu.be/pOizNEV5WNw?feature=shared&t=160

@KerrAvon2055 there were some good scenes with G'Kar.

That is exactly it! But it's so much more cringey than I remembered. I forgot this show existed but it's funny that I asked this question because I just finished re-watching B5 and Crusade and something kept making me think of the martial arts ship scenes.

@FuzzyBoots It most certainly does not show up in Crusade, thank goodness.

@succulent_headcrab And boy has that CG not aged well...
